# Merging multiple ranges into one range variable

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Simple worksheet]

I have a sheet containing three cells. I am trying to take these 3 ranges and store them all in a separate range variable to be presented in a MsgBox.

I'm sure there are better options but i'm really trying to store multiple ranges in one range.

```
Sub mergingRanges()
    Dim MergedRange As Range
    MergedRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1") & ActiveSheet.Range("A2") & ActiveSheet.Range("A3")
    MsgBox MergedRange
End Sub
```

This returns a compilation error but ideally, it would return the 15,16,17

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union

Comment: You want `MergedRange` to be a string not a range.

Comment: @braX ```MergedRange = Union(Range("A1"), Range("A2"), Range("A3"))``` returns a ```Run-time error 91, object variables or with block variable not set ```. Unsure how to debug, the synatax seems to only allow 2 ranges which might be the reason

Comment: The error was because you did not use `Set` - but it looks like you have a full answer now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a Range variable containing the three cells, you have several options.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim MergedRange As Range 
    ' Simple
    Set MergedRange = .Range("A1:A3")

    ' Use From and To Cell to Define the Range
    Set MergedRange = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A3"))
    ' Or
    Set MergedRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 1))
   
    ' Use Resize
    Set MergedRange = .Range("A1").Resize(3, 1)

    ' Use Union (usefull if cells are not next to each other)
    Set MergedRange = Union(.Range("A1"), .Range("A2"), .Range("A3"))
End If
```

Be aware that a Range is an Object and in VBA you have to use `Set` to assign an Object. And be aware that you can't do something like `MsgBox MergedRange` when `MergedRange` contains more than one cell. This is because for a command like `MsgBox MergedRange`, VBA will look to the content of the Range (property `Value`), and for a Range with more than one cell, this is an (2-dimensional) array.